# добавление в textarea текста где курсор

Tags: javascript, html

Столкнулся с проблемой - как в textarea вставлять текст туда, где находится курсор по нажатию кнопки. Это может быть bb-code или подготовленный текст

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решением этого послужила самописная конструкция

```js
function insertText( id, text ) {
  //ищем элемент по id
 var txtarea = document.getElementById(id);
 //ищем первое положение выделенного символа
 var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
 //ищем последнее положение выделенного символа
 var end = txtarea.selectionEnd;
 // текст до + вставка + текст после (если этот код не работает, значит у вас несколько id)
 var finText = txtarea.value.substring(0, start) + text + txtarea.value.substring(end);
 // подмена значения
 txtarea.value = finText;
 // возвращаем фокус на элемент
 txtarea.focus();
 // возвращаем курсор на место - учитываем выделили ли текст или просто курсор поставили
 txtarea.selectionEnd = ( start == end )? (end + text.length) : end ;
}
$('.add_text').click(function(){
 insertText('info_sms_id', $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="text" placeholder="Текст для вставки" id="info_sms_id"></textarea>
<br/>
<input class="add_text" type="button" value="#Итого">
<input class="add_text" type="button" value="#Товар">
<input class="add_text" type="button" value="#№Заказа">
```